# ERROR [AxisEngine] Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have gone through all the related posts here , but did not get any solution
I have generated Web Services Client code with `wsdl2java` with `Apache Axis2 1.4.1`

The wsdl is having the following

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="DigitalSignatureWithCertificateAndTimestampPolicy" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"
            xmlns:wsrmp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/policy" xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All alternative-id="DigitalSignatureWithCertificateAndTimestampPolicy">
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Always"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Always"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:Body/>
            </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

But when checked the soap request envelop , no policy header found.

And I have got following error while doing a web-service request .

```
ERROR [AxisEngine] Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd : Security
o
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.checkMustUnderstand(AxisEngine.java:102)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:363)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:416)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
```

Can anyone help me to sort this out?